# how to use a custom functional component in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-functional-component

how to use a functional custom component in react native??? i actualy build a login functional component like a custom react but not exsist a  "div" i made a "View"
why should this not work??

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

    const Login = () => {
    return (
        <View>
          <Text>Hi</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    export default Login;

--------------------------------- 
    import React from 'react';
    import {Login} from './components/Login/Login';
    import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
    
    const App = () => {
        return (
        <View>
          <Login/>
       </View>
        )
     }
     export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your [named exports and default exports](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910) turned around.

This would work instead:

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

    const Login = () => {
    return (
        <View>
          <Text>Hi</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    export default Login;

--------------------------------- 
    import React from 'react';
    import Login from './components/Login/Login';
    import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
    
    const App = () => {
        return (
        <View>
          <Login/>
       </View>
        )
     }
     export default App;
```

When you `export default Login`, you must import it as a default import with `import Login from './components/Login/Login'`

[Here is an Expo Snack with the working code as well](https://snack.expo.dev/@coolsoftwaretyler/stack-overflow-71083821)

Comment: oh my god its lack of attention thank youu  :)

Comment: All good! We all make mistakes sometimes, haha. Good luck!